# Wlan Empfang schlecht// Wlan reception very bad

Tags: 12.04, wireless, firefox, internet, router

On Windows 8 the Wlan reception was great,no problems. But since I have Ubuntu 12.04, the reception is very bad. When I move a few meter from my router,my Internet slows down...

Have anyone an idea or a tip for me?

---

Hallo an alle Deutsch-Sprachigen hier im Forum :)

Auf Windows 8 hat ich keine Probleme mit dem WLan Empfang,alles lief super. Aber seit dem ich Ubuntu 12.04 auf dem Laptop habe,ist der Empfang sehr schlecht. Sobald ich ein paar Meter vom Router weggehe,wird alles sehr langsam. (FritzBox)

Hat irgendjemand eine Idee bzw einen Tipp?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up your router to an other frequency. The settings of fritz!box are available with your browser under the address fritz.box. This is because a neighbour could use the same frequency as you use. But I think that's not really a good answer.
/
Es könnte sein, dass ein Nachbar die gleiche Frequenz wie du Nutzt. Ändere diese doch mal.
Aber diese Antwort ist sehr unwahrscheinlich richtig.